# iOS - Add a custom toolbar between NavBar and PullToRefreslh

Tags: ios, uitableview, toolbar

I would like to add a second "toolbar" fixed under my NavigationBar.

I've a class which inherit from [PullToRefreshViewController class](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh) and which inherit from UITableViewController.

But I want to do something like Facebook app just under the notifications:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LwH0.png

I don't know how to do this, could you give me advices please ?
Create a custom TableViewController class doesn't seem to be easy ...

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just add a toolbar in IB and set the PullToRefreshControllers frame?

```
pullToRefreshController.frame = CGRectMake(0, newToolBar.frame.size.height+navBar.frame.size.height, 320, self.view.frame.size.height-(newToolBar.frame.size.height+navBar.frame.size.height));
```

Like so?
If not, I will switch to my mac and try to find a solution.

Comment: Seem to be a good way, now I've an empty area and I can not add my toolbar in.
 ---> 
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, self.view.frame.size.height-44);
UIView *tbview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 88, 320, 44)];
UIToolbar *uitb = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    uitb.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 44);
[tbview addSubview:uitb];
//[self.view addSubview:tbview];

Comment: UIToolbar *uitb = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 88, 320, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:uitb];

This should work. You just have to remember to do it in the viewDidLoad-method, and not in the init. If you still can't get it working, you could try adding it in InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: I can't add this to my self.view, it works but the toolbar is added in the scrolling part, and I want it just before like in empty area you create in your first answer.

And I can not add toolbar in my IB idk why ...

I think maybe it's because of my implementation because PullToRefresh class of Leah need a TableViewController and not just a TableView :/

Comment: You need to add the UIToolBar to the the ViewController (if you have one) that holds the PullToRefreshController. If you don't have a top-viewcontroller, you will need to add this to your project.

Self is the top-level viewcontroller:

PullToRefreshController *push = [[PullToRefreshController alloc] init....];

[self.view addSubview:push.view];

UIToolbar *uitb = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 88, 320, 44)]; 
[self.view addSubview:uitb];

Comment: Finaly I've rewrite PullToRefresh code of Leah ( https://github.com/Flemzard/PullToRefresh ), now it's more proper and it works with me :) Thanks for your help !